# How to create multiple instances of nodejs server

Tags: node.js, express, session, chat, multiple-users

I am building a `notification application` in which every time an event is triggered the associated user gets a notification. I am using `localstorage` of NodeJs to store the information of the logged in user. The problem is that when two users are logged in,the `localstorage` values are overridden by the new users value.

I need to create `multiple instances of NodeJS server` so that every user has its own `localStorage`.

For example
If two users log in with credentials

```
{
userName:name1
}
```

and

```
{
userName:name2
}
```

then two separate localStorage should be created one having `userName:name1` and one having `userName:name2`.

I have tried all the solutions available online but I am unable to create multiple states of NodeJS server.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can use redis for saving key/value pair username

Comment: I would also suggest you to use redis, but if you are doing something more complex then you should use database, i would suggest you NoSQL DBs (firebase, mongodb, postgreSQL, etc..)

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to create a new server for each user. Take the IP address and port instead. This means that each user can be uniquely identified. You can simply name the files of the users after the variable client.

Here an example code

```js
net.createServer((netSocket : net.Socket) => {
    netSocket.on('data', (data) => {
         var client = netSocket.remoteAddress + ':' + netSocket.remotePort;
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to create multiple nodejs instances hence I stored the user data in session storage and passed it to nodejs server every time I triggered a request.